# Distance from point to foot of perpendicular

Tags: geometry

> Given a point $(u,v)$ in $[0,1]^2$, what are the coordinates of the foot of the perpendicular from $(u,v)$ to the line $x=y$?

The foot has the coordinates $\Big( \frac{u+v}{2}, \frac{u+v}{2} \Big)$.
How is this calculated?

$(\frac{u+v}{2},\frac{u+v}{2})$ is also the midpoint of the line between $(u,u)$ and $(v,v)$, which are both on the line $x=y$, but it's not clear to me why this is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reflect $(u,v)$ over the line $y=x$ you get $(v,u)$. The line joining those two points is perpendicular to and bisected by the diagonal.

If you draw the picture and locate $(u,u)$ and $(v,v)$ you will see a square that answers your second question.